# compare two different collection with the column value

Tags: mongodb

I have two different collection, customer and prospect. _Id(customer collection) is presented in prospect collection with the name of customerId.. Now I want to get the customer details based on the customerid. how to achieve it

[image: customer_collection]

```
db.getCollection('st_salesquotes').find({CustomerId:'5a66f2549ca9b27c4df31e62'})
```

I want to display the customers who are all present in salesquote based on the _id(customer collection)

Comment: u can achieve using lookup
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: Screen shots doesn't work here... please try to post some sample collections instead

Comment: You need to use Mongo Lookup in order to get the Aggregate data from both the collections.